# Boot fails for linux 5.4.0-65-generic kernel

Tags: boot, kernel

When booting my lenovo laptop, all I see is:

```
Loading Linux 5.4.0-65-generic ...
Loading initial ramdisk ...
```

And then in hangs there forever.

I used to be able to go into the GRUB menu and select `elementary, with Linux 5.4.0-40-generic` and that would boot elementaryOS 5.1 successfully. But that option has now gone away in the GRUB menu. I believe what happened is at some point I ran `apt autoremove`, which uninstalled that older linux kernel.

My question is how do I reinstall the older linux kernel (`5.4.0-40-generic`) or how do I figure out why the newer linux kernel (`5.4.0-65-generic`) isn't working.

**Edit**:

Since I originally posted this, I have new information. I reinstalled elementary OS from a live USB and I found that will update the kernel to 5.4.0-65-generic and that boots just fine. I thought I had solved my problem, but then I ran `apt update` and `apt upgrade` and now my computer doesn't boot again. So I believe that sometime in the past month, one or multiple of those packages being upgraded is messing up the boot process on my laptop.

I reinstalled again, but this time only ran `apt update` and here is what I get when I run `apt list --upgradeable`: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WwXHdkYkBx/

Comment: Grub > advanced > recovery mode -- does that work to get you in at least?

Comment: Yeah, that boots into the recovery mode and that's how I've been able to back up my data

Comment: You can install another kernel or you can try to fix it so that the current kernel boots. What happens when it doesn't boot normally?

Comment: I added new information related to my problem in the post, I am working on getting the list of upgraded packages posted.